# How does greenDao @toMany relation deletion procedure work?

Tags: android, sqlite, one-to-many, greendao, greendao3

So, I have two models: `Document` and `Item`. Table creation and insertion works just perfect. What I want to know is that if I do something like this:

```
mDaoSession.getDocumentDao().deleteInTx(selectedDocuments);
//or
mDaoSession.getDocumentDao().deleteByKeyInTx(documentIds);
```

Will any of queries above delete all `Items` related to this `Document` or should I do it manually (with additional code)? If not deleting is there any way in `GreenDao` to accomplish that?

**Document.class**

```
public class Document {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long documentId;
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "id")
    public List<Item> items;
}
```

**Item.class**

```
public class Item {

    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: could you resolve it?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I used conventional way of deletion.